# My scroll div's work on pc but not on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-browser

I am trying to make a social networking site. To display comments, I made two divs. Here are the `css` codes for them:

```
#bigbox{ 
float:right; 
background:white; 
width:45%; 
height:450px; 
border-left: 5px solid #4CAF50;
}



#rightbox{ 
float:right; 
background:white; 
width:95%; 
height:100%;
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
padding: 15px;
}
```

I use `rightbox` div inside of the `bigbox`.

On my computer, there is no problem but on mobile, when comments overflow, they go across the site.

I tested with Firefox and Chromium on PC and Chrome, Opera, DuckDuckGo and Firefox on mobile.

Comment: you mean the 2 divs are overlapping?

Comment: Never use float to design, unless you want text to float around images. Float messes up the elements. Use flex, grid or, in some instances, position: fixed.

Comment: @RickardElimää I am fine with the positions, only scroll does not work.

Comment: The issue is probably because you're using float, hence my comment.